# Data filter "from, to" Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, filter

Here's my json :

```
[
    {
        "name": "2QQQJohnQQQ11_12_1998",
        "age" : "18"
    },
    {
        "name": "1QQQEvaQQQ05_11_1989",
        "age" : "21"
    },
    {
        "name": "4QQQCasperQQQ12_06_1994",
        "age" : "13"
    },
    {
        "name": "3QQQBeanQQQ30_12_1996",
        "age" : "6"
    }]
```

My Html :

```
 <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="text-center">type</th>
                        <th class="text-center">name</th>
                        <th class="text-center">date</th>
                        <th class="text-center">age</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="name in namesplit | filter:dateFilterFunction | orderBy:'time'">
                        <td>{{name.type}}</td>
                        <td>{{name.name}}</td>
                        <td>{{name.time | date}}</td>
                        <td>{{name.age}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
```

My javascript file:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.service('service', function($http, $q){
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http.get("datesss.json").then(function(data){
            deferred.resolve(data);
        });

        this.getNames = function(){
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    });
    app.controller('secondCtrl', function($scope, service){
        var promise = service.getNames();
        promise.then(function(data){
            $scope.names = data.data;
            $scope.namesplit = $scope.names;
            $scope.namesplit.map(function(item) {
                item.type = item.name.split('QQQ')[0];
                item.data = item.name.split('QQQ')[2].split('_');
                item.name = item.name.split('QQQ')[1];
                item.time = new Date(parseInt(item.data[2],10),parseInt(item.data[1],10)-1,parseInt(item.data[0],10));
        });
    });
});
```

I am doing a table and what i try to do is filter "from, to" which filters the data (name.time). My code in HTML :

```
<input type="date" ng-model="dateFilter.from" class="form-control" />
<input type="date" ng-model="dateFilter.to" class="form-control" />
```

My code in controller:

```
$scope.dateFilter={};
                $scope.dateFilterFunction= function(name){
                    return (name.time>$scope.dateFilter.from && name.time<$scope.dateFilter.to);
        }
```

it didn't work. Someone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the output of your code, I mean what are you getting now?

Comment: Nothing in my table, but when i delete from ng-repeat "filter:dateFilterFunction" i have everything work

Comment: Are you having the error only with your input without a value? In that case try to initialise your filters with a null vale, $scope.dateFilter={from:null, to:null};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [date filter](https://plnkr.co/edit/uFFkzfOYUBw1riFSVxTA?p=preview)

We need to declare the filter as follows:-

```
.filter('dateFilterFunction',function(){
  return function(data, from, to) {
    if (!from && !to) return data;
    var newData = [];
    angular.forEach(data, function(item){
      if (item.time >= from && item.time <= to) {
           newData.push(item);  
      }

    });
    return newData;
  };
});
```

Comment: can you give me a hint, what to change in this filter to filters the data ex only "for", without "to"?

Comment: So if you don't need `to` you can remove the 3rd argument so that it looks like `return function(data, from)` AND change `dateFilterFunction:dateFilter.from:dateFilter.to` to `dateFilterFunction:dateFilter.from` essentially removing `dateFiler.to`. Every `:` acts as a way to pass arguments to the filter function.

Comment: I meant that, the filter be able to filtering "from, to" and singly "from" or singly "to" :) Thanks a lot for answers!

Comment: Try something like `(from && item.time >= from) || (to && item.time <= to)` basically we are using OR condition.